# editing .htaccess to direct the public/index.php fie in subdomain on share hosting Hostinger

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out how to direct the .htaccess file in the root of my subdomain to the public/index.php file, so that the server will load the file. But I also lack any knowledge regarding with .htaccess file.

Trying to connect to

public_html/absolute/public/index.php

from

public_html/absolute/.htaccess

.htaccess file inside public_html/absolute

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*) public/$l [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

It would also be really helpful, if I was given any source to learn more about .htaccess file configuration for project deployment!

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying to access files deployed via git on the public_html/absolute through the link https://www.coffeesojava.xyz/absolute/ but it keps on saying 404 the .htaccess in the absolute path which is the subdomain is as displayed above

Comment: Remove `RewriteBase /` and retest

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I actually noticed that I can asset the files through www.coffeesojava.xyz/absolute/public. And I am just going to access through the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in `public_html/absolute/.htaccess`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will allow you to use `https://www.coffeesojava.xyz/absolute/`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the files can be accessed throgh the [www.doamin.com/subdomain/public](http://www.doamin.com/subdomain/public) link after deleting the .htaccess in the subdomain root folder. Goo luck guys!